# Whats that strange symbols and how to heal it?

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, windows-10-universal

Just want to make style for all buttons in a stackpanel.

```
<StackPanel Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
             <Style TargetType="Button">
                 <Setter Property="Background" Value="Aquamarine"/>
             </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>                               
     <Button x:Name="Btn_ButtonClose" Content="Close" FontSize="32">                        
     </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

And VS shows error in error list (characters AS IS):

￐ﾝ￐ﾵ ￑ﾃ￐ﾴ￐ﾰ￐ﾻ￐ﾾ￑ﾁ￑ﾌ ￐ﾸ￐ﾷ￐ﾼ￐ﾵ￐ﾽ￐ﾸ￑ﾂ￑ﾌ ￐ﾷ￐ﾽ￐ﾰ￑ﾇ￐ﾵ￐ﾽ￐ﾸ￐ﾵ ￑ﾀ￐ﾵ￑ﾁ￑ﾃ￑ﾀ￑ﾁ￐ﾰ "Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button".

Whats that mean? Is my VS broken?

Comment: These code should work well, do you always get this error even in a new blank uwp app? If so, maybe you should try to repaire your Visual studio.

Comment: After I rebuild a solution(F6) errors cleared and never appear. In a blank uwp app I got such symbols only if I added a Adcontrol at AppId and UnitId strings in XAML. But it is work and this errors appears rarely. I fear repair VS, cause some time ago it was terrible experience and I had to reinstall OS. Maybe later I will try to repair it.

Answer (score -1):

As for me the 15.7.3 VS update heals the issue. Two days, none of that strange errors symbols.